# MySQL8 query whole bloodline (ancestors + descendants) of a hierarchy

Tags: mysql, recursion, common-table-expression, recursive-query

MySQL8 allows using `with` syntax to query hierarchical structures. For instance, querying all ancestors of an item. Conversely, all descendants also can be queried recursively.

[image]

I'm looking for a query that combines these two aspects: a query of all descendants, ancestors, and optimally the item self (see at the included graphic, all colorized items). Actually, you also could say, all items without the siblings of all ancestors. I think we could say "bloodline". It's possible just to `union` the two results but I need a solution without union.

Is that possible at all? I would welcome any approach.

For an overview, my union attempt. Note, that there's currently an error, some parent_id are wrong; I'm working on that)

```sql
(with recursive cte as (
    SELECT id, parent_id
    from categories
    where id = 'C2'
    union all
    select t.parent_id, cte.id
    from cte
             inner join categories t on t.id = cte.parent_id
    where cte.id is not null
)
 select id, parent_id
 from cte
 where cte.id is not null)

union

(with recursive cte as (
    SELECT id, parent_id
    from categories
    where id = 'C2'
    union all
    select t.id, cte.parent_id
    from cte
             inner join categories t on t.parent_id = cte.id
)
 select id, parent_id
 from cte);
```

and the data for the given diagram.

```sql
INSERT INTO categories (id, parent_id) VALUES ('A1', null);
INSERT INTO categories (id, parent_id) VALUES ('B1', 'A1');
INSERT INTO categories (id, parent_id) VALUES ('B2', 'A1');
INSERT INTO categories (id, parent_id) VALUES ('B3', 'A1');
INSERT INTO categories (id, parent_id) VALUES ('C1', 'B2');
INSERT INTO categories (id, parent_id) VALUES ('C2', 'B2');
INSERT INTO categories (id, parent_id) VALUES ('D1', 'C1');
INSERT INTO categories (id, parent_id) VALUES ('D2', 'C1');
INSERT INTO categories (id, parent_id) VALUES ('D3', 'C2');
INSERT INTO categories (id, parent_id) VALUES ('D4', 'C2');
INSERT INTO categories (id, parent_id) VALUES ('D5', 'C2');
INSERT INTO categories (id, parent_id) VALUES ('E1', 'D5');
```

**Expected output**

```
id,parent_id
C2,B2
A1,null
B2,A1
D3,C2
D4,C2
D5,C2
E1,D5
```

Comment: So we don't have the feeling that we are solving your homework for you, please provide at least your attempt with the union (which you implied you can do), then we can tell you how to write it without a  union. Or if you want to try it yourself, an idea would be: you can combine your two recursive queries that each walk in a different direction (but otherwise do the same) by building one recursive query that encodes the direction in a new column (or, to give it a nice meaning, the search depth, e.g. grandfather=-2, children=+1, ...), and then use `or` to combine your walk-conditions.

Comment: I've added my union attempt with the corresponding DDL and data. Your idea supports me, but I'll have to take a closer detailed look at it.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: All colorized items starting from C2 (A1, B2, C2, D3, D4, D5 and E1) in the graphic.

Comment: Do you really need the 2nd column parent_id in the results? A row with id=A1 and parent_id=C2 does not make sense.

Comment: Oh sorry. I made a mistake. Some parent_id were wrong. I've corrected the expected output. But there's also a mistake in my query. Later, I want to use it in a query builder, so actually I need all columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with 1 recursive CTE, if you include both conditions for the ancestors and descendants in the ON clause.
You will need another column `type` which indicates whether each row is for an ancestor or descendant:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT id, parent_id, 0 type
    FROM categories
    WHERE id = 'C2'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.id, t.parent_id,
           CASE WHEN c.parent_id = t.id THEN -1 ELSE 1 END
    FROM categories t INNER JOIN cte c
    ON c.parent_id = t.id OR c.id = t.parent_id
    WHERE (type = 0) 
       OR (c.parent_id = t.id AND type = -1) 
       OR (c.id = t.parent_id AND type = 1)
)
SELECT id, parent_id FROM cte
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5bb43321175e866f77d548a106173c8d).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I need.